# jquery delegate elements in infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using this "simple" code to assign a pin id to the container divs and click to open the .pin-card content.

This works fine, but when I add the [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) script, this code does not work for new elements that are loaded.

```
$(document).on("click", ".showImage", function() {
    $('.pin-card').not('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();    
    $('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
});
```

Only open works thanks to the deferred invention .showImage

```
$(document).on("click", ".showImage", function() {
```

the rest doesn't work:

```
 $('.pin-card').not('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();    
    $('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="masonry-item">
    <a class="showImage" target="28">
        <img src="">
    </a>
         <!-- open div -->
         <div id="pin28" class="pin-card" style="display: none;">
            <div class="close"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
          </div>
          <!-- end open div -->
</div>
```

It's all pretty simple but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

any ideas?

**EDIT** an example of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/dlopezros/dw2snxtp/20/
or in operation at: https://shop.midimal.es/collections/string-inspiracion

Comment: Generating a simple snippet / [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35mcyv7d/) of the code provided shows that your code, as provided, works fine.   So the issue must be around the `infinite-scroll` plugin.  Perhaps it's not generating the HTML that you're expecting?   Please [edit] your question and include a working snippet *that includes infinite-scroll and how you are using it*.   See [mcve].   So we can see what's going wrong outside of the provided details.  Easiest option is for you to debug the output (network tab / inspect elements)

Comment: Update: the specific [tag:infinite-scroll] that you've linked has a commercial licence - you should contact your supplier for support.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m You can see an example of the code at https://jsfiddle.net/dlopezros/dw2snxtp/20/
or in operation at: https://shop.midimal.es/collections/string-inspiracion

Comment: @freedomn-m the problem is not caused by the infinite-scroll. The problem stems from my click event code

Comment: Each time your infinit-scroll loads new data, the loaded data starts again from pin0.  So after a page or two, you have *multiple* entries with the same `id='pin0'`.  You can confirm this by opening the page (don't scroll) open console and enter `$("[id=pin0]").length` (==0) - then scroll to bottom so the paging kicks in and enter again (>0).   IDs must be unique.  So when you click on the 5th `target=0` then you get the *first* `id=pin0`.  Add `console.log($(this).attr('target'))` to your showImage click event - this must always increase for each additional page rather than reset.

Comment: In conclusion, the issue is *not* your click code (as already demonstrated) but *how you are using infinite-scroll* - or, more specifically, how you are implementing **paging** (which the infinite-scroll simply invokes, it's not doing anything itself).   Your targets + ids need to add pagenum*rowcount to the target/pin IDs.

Comment: Based on your HTML layout, you could *remove IDs completely* and do: `$(".pin-card").hide(); $(this).next().show();`  (or a toggle version, but as the card appears over the thumb, toggle seems pointless) https://jsfiddle.net/j54v7wcx/

Comment: @freedomn-m I am using the pin IDs to be able to open them from the browser with hash #pin28
In that case, what could I do?  thanks

Comment: See comments above.  Try it *without* the infinite-scroll - when you click next page you get a page of 0->28 again - so what should #pin28 be in that case?   If you need IDs for URL linking, then keep them, for thumb->card you don't need ID.